# Unable to import SVG file into React

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, ecmascript-6, loader

I'm using React v15.4.1. I've followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844298/how-do-i-load-svgs-directly-in-my-react-component-using-webpack) but in the place of where the component should be rendered, I am only getting a string like this `https://localhost:3001/dist/7553ed8d42edb0d73754cd9a5dea2168.svg`

My React component is set up like:

```
import theSVGicon from 'path/to/icon.svg';
...
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: theSVGicon }} />
```

**Other Notes:**

1. The image renders fine when I include it as the `src` in an `image` like this: `<img src={theSVGicon}/>`
2. Code like the bottom of [this](http://jxnblk.com/react-icons/) page does work: 
   `<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="64" height="64" fill="currentcolor">
   <path d="M 28.495430026136273 0 L 35.504569973863724 0 L 37.22908963117581 ... 0 0 0 32 20"></path>
   </svg>`
3. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs) solution, I do see an `svg` component rendered, along with the other attributes. I also see the spacing for where it should be, but it is blank. More details:

[image: from element inspector] 
[image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpoXP.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpoXP.jpg)

4. Ideally, I want to set up my svg image like in (3) above so that I can tweak attributes like `viewBox` and `height`, which is supported in the latest React version.

Is something wrong with my loader? I am using Webpack and rendering server side using [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools). I didn't want to look too much into this since it does work with an `img` and I have code that is supposed to handle SVGs based off of an earlier version of a [boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example):

**dev.config.js**

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
      ...
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  },
...
```

**webpack-isomorphic-tools.js**

```
...
assets: {
    ...
    svg: {
      extension: 'svg',
      parser: WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.url_loader_parser
    },
...
```

My last-ditch effort would be to redo and follow [this](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/wiki/Importing-SVGs)

Answer (score 1):

Use [svg-inline-react](https://github.com/sairion/svg-inline-react) as an loader and to load svg as inline

```
{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline' }
```

with specify the svg-inline loader it should work with your below line

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: UpvoteFist }} />
```

but if only loader doesn't work for you then follow the guidlines they given as

```
import InlineSVG from 'svg-inline-react'; // ES2015
```

.......

```
 <InlineSVG src={require("svg-inline!icon.svg")} /> // Use with loader
```

Comment: putting it as the `src` in an `img` does work for me, but I wanted to render it as an svg-inline.

Comment: Yeah, the svg-inline loader doesn't work for me. It would then throw an error about not being able to parse through a font awesome svg file in one of my node modules. Your second suggestion doesn't work either with a lot of `svg-inline-loader doesn't exist` doesn't exist errors. If you have one, I'm wondering how your webpack-isomorphic-tools.js file looks like? I think this guide is my closest chance for getting it to work: https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/wiki/Importing-SVGs . One of the main things I need to figure out is why `svg` for me isn't included in images: extensions [...

Comment: I'm getting the same error whether `require`-ing the loader directly or setting it in my webpack config: [1] [piping] error given was: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
[1]     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
[1]     at Object._module2.default._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .webpack-loaders] (/path/to/app/node_modules/webpack-isomorphic-tools/node_modules/require-hacker/babel-transpiled-modules/require hacker.js:274:11)`

Comment: My solution may lie in here as I'm getting similar problems and used the same boilerplate app: https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools/issues/59