# React - render imported .svg file

Tags: reactjs, svg

I need to render .svg files. I do not want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I am able to successfully render an svg if I copy the svg contents directly and render it from a component.

However, this is not very reusable. I don't want to copy the contents from each .svg file. I would like to be able to import an svg file and pass that into my component that will then render the contents.

Here's what I have done so far, but it is not rendering my svg.

I have created a component that accepts an imported svg file, like this:

```
import React from "react";

class SvgComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }
  render() {  
    return (
     props.svg // this works if I copy my .svg contents here (<svg>....</svg>)
  );
 }
};

SvgComponent.propTypes = {
  svg: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default SvgComponent;
```

And here is how I am using that component:

```
import mySvg from './images/mySvg.svg';
const Icon = (props) => { 
  return (
    <svgComponent svg={mySvg} />
  );
};

Icon.propTypes = {
  icon: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Icon;
```

This does not work -- it does not show my svg on the webpage, or even in the dom. When I inspect the page, all I see is an empty svgComponent:

```
<svgComponent />
```

Any help on getting .svg files to display in react would great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load SVGs directly in my React component using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844298/how-do-i-load-svgs-directly-in-my-react-component-using-webpack)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I do not want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Comment: Fair enough. I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I created a module to solve this problem. With it you can load the svg and manipulate its elements using JSX without having to paste the svg code.

Npm package:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-samy-svg

Check an example on Glitch: https://fossil-transport.glitch.me

It's simple to use

```html
<Samy path="path to your svg file">
     <Proxy select="#Star" fill="red"/>
 </Samy>
```

Whenever you need to change some SVG attribute just create a Proxy element and use the 'select' prop (accepts CSS selectors). All props set on Proxy will be forwared as attributes to the SVG element(s)

Comment: Thanks. This loads the following in the DOM, but does not display the image. <div class="" data-src="../images/myImage.svg" src=""></div>

Comment: I have the following       <Samy path="../images/myImage.svg"></Samy>

Comment: Here is the error in the console: Failed child context type: Invalid child context `svg` of type `string` supplied to `Samy`, expected `object`.

Comment: Looks like that path is not resolving correctly. You can check the network tab in devtools to see if the request is successful and adjust the path.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? If so you can import the svg: import mySvg from '../images/myImage.svg' and then use path={mySvg}

Comment: importing my image an using      <Samy path={mySVG}> </Samy> . Still same error

Comment: Then, please try with <Samy path={myImage}></Samy>

Comment: sorry, I am using  <Samy path={myImage}></Samy>

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. I have an example on Glitch, it loads an external svg and displays it. ( https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fossil-transport?path=src/App.js:10:22 ) . If you can share the code I may be able to help you. ( hugozap@gmail.com )